# How to determine all details should go to first line item if we have multiple duplicate dates?

Tags: mysql, sql

1)I have four fields like material  no, item no, date, quantity.

Input:

```
   Material  item    date               quantity
    101       91    06/05/2020             4
    101       92    06/05/2020             6
    101       93    06/05/2020             4
```

Requirement is we need to consider date as reference

2) If date is repeated twice or n number of times , the output should goes to first item with adding quantity.

Output:

```
        Material  item       date            quantity
          101       91        06/05/2020           14
```

Comment: *the output should goes to first item* First/second/last/etc not exists until explicit unique ORDER BY specified. So what ordering is used for to make "first item" exised? ORDER BY item ASC?

Comment: Thanks for quick response.There should be some unique id to refer first item right?

Comment: Its ordered by item ASC

Comment: How to implement java code for this problem ? please suggest

Comment: What is your MySQL version? If there exists rows with the same `date` but different `material` does the output must have one row? one row per `material`?

Comment: I am not sure about version because we don't have access to DB. Business will provide querys they will maintain DB.

Comment: if there exists rows with same date but different material the output should be one row per materal

Comment: *I am not sure about version because we don't have access to DB.* What is a problem to execute `SELECT VERSION();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to run the following SQL query:

```
SELECT `material`, `date`, MIN(item), SUM(quantity)
FROM `your_table`
GROUP BY `material`,`date`
```

JDBC Example:

```
String sql = "SELECT `material`, `date`, MIN(item) AS item, SUM(quantity) AS quantity "
           + "FROM `your_table` "
           + "GROUP BY `material`,`date`";
try (
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    Statement  stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet  rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
) {
  while (rs.next()) {
     //Retrieve by column name
     int material = rs.getInt("material");
     Date date = rs.getDate("date");
     int item = rs.getInt("item");
     int quantity = rs.getInt("quantity");

     //Display values
     System.out.printf("%d\t%s\t%d\t%d%n", material, date, item, quantity);
  }
}
```

**Update**

If MySQL 8 is used it should be possible to use its [`FIRST_VALUE` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value) to locate first item in a group.

Otherwise, the query may be rewritten to use subquery with LIMIT 1 for `item`:

```
SELECT `material`, `date`, SUM(quantity),
(
    SELECT item 
    FROM `your_table` in_tab 
    WHERE in_tab.material = out_tab.material AND in_tab.`date`=out_tab.`date` 
    LIMIT 1) AS item
FROM `your_table` out_tab
GROUP BY `material`,`date`
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its really help me a lot.

Comment: I have seen few more examples , some of them in item field its like Not ASC and DESC as well in that case we cannot implement right . We don't know what is the first line item.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: There are some cases for above requirement where item number is neither ASC order nor DESC as well. If that case we cannot know what is first line item right? There should be some field to identify what is the first item number?